# Outputting formatted code to view in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am hoping there is a solution to this,
I have an example MVC application, and I want to output formatted snippets of code to the browser 
Something like the following

```
ViewBag.PageSource = "

    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        [RegularExpression("[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,64}", ErrorMessage = "username must contain  letters or numbers only, and be between 2 and 64 characters long ")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

    }

";
```

Is this sort of thing  possible ?

I have a modal popup in the main layout file and I wanted this to contain the source (model/controller) snippets for each view, by placing it in a viewbag variable in each view

Comment: Are you looking out for [Google code prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to do this at the controller. That's what the view is for.

code.google.com & Stackoverflow use [Code-Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

You can then use it with the pre tags:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
    public class RegisterViewModel<br/>
    {<br/>
        [Required]<br/>
        [Display(Name = "User name")]<br/>
        [RegularExpression("[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,64}", ErrorMessage = "username must contain    letters or numbers only, and be between 2 and 64 characters long ")]<br/>
        public string UserName { get; set; }<br/>
<br/>
}<br/>
</pre>
```

Comment: Yes, however its quite a lot of code I need to reformat, I was hoping for an easier solution. I have a modal popup in the main layout file and i wanted this to contain the source (model/controller) snippets for each view, by placing it in a viewbag variable in each view

Answer (score 0):

If snippet is dynamicly generated you have to use JavaScript formatted.

For example

*SyntaxHighlighter is good client-side solution:*

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

In other case take a look here

*Jon Skeet provides a code formatter for public use:*

http://csharpindepth.com/CodeFormatterTool.aspx

**UPDATE**

Seems to me that SO use this https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: No not dynamically generated, just copy pasted from the model/controller

Comment: Take a look http://csharpindepth.com/CodeFormatterTool.aspx you can generate html that you need for snippets.

Comment: Yes , thats great however I wanted to put them in a view bag variable in each view so this can be outputted on every page ( via a modal popup in the main layout file Thanks for the resource though , I never knew that existed

Comment: I don't understand why you are going put it to ViewBag. You can put to view bag name of partial view with this generated code. And invoke @Html.Partial(ViewBag.PageSourcePartialView) for example.

Comment: But if you really want put it to ViewBag use http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ For spaces use @" ... code here... " I mean verbatim string literal http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, anything is possible. Add the @ sign in front of first " and multi-line strings will work.

Then you need to do something about the tabs. You could use `<pre>` tag or replace tabs with a fixed-width div.

Answer (score 0):

For HTML5 you should use `<pre><code>//your code here</code></pre>`.